# Grunt not working: -bash: exec: grunt: not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I installed node v0.8.14 on Mac OS 10.7.5. I then installed Grunt with `npm install -g grunt`.

Node works perfectly, Grunt doesn't. It keeps saying: **`-bash: exec: grunt: not found`**

**Any idea what I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, npm installs into /usr/local. Try `/usr/local/bin/grunt` in your shell. To allow you to simply type `grunt`, add

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

to the `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Although grunt now seems to work, it doesn't completely. When trying to run grint init, I get this node error: `node.js:134 throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick`

Comment: Is that the entire error message you get? Can you elaborate on what you mean by *stick*? Once you add the changed `PATH` in `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`), it will be applied whenever you start a new shell.

Comment: It didn't. Don't know why. I added the `PATH` export to `.bashrc`, then reloaded it. Now it sticks. Oh, and I added `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin"`. Now it passes.

Comment: AFAIK `/usr/local/bin` is on the path by default in OS X since OS X 10.6 at least, if not longer. So it's likely here that PATH is set somewhere without adding back the previously set $PATH to the new PATH before or after setting the new path strings.